# Docker Phantomjs driver access

Tags: java, docker, phantomjs

I have one docker container, its spring-boot application. From this docker container I want to access local phantomjs driver. When I run my container in docker, it gives 'The driver executable does not exist: /usr/bin/phantomjs' exception but my phantomjs driver is exist under this path. 
How does this docker container can access '/usr/bin/phantomjs' file?
Should I add  this line VOLUME /usr/bin/phantomjs in docker file ?
phantomjs version is : 2.1.1

Comment: You shouldn't access a local executable from a docker image, you need to use a phantomjs docker image

Comment: From your docker container, run `file /usr/bin/phantomjs`. What do you get?

Comment: Which image base are you using? Did you check the runner user into container can execute this file?

Comment: @SiKing, when I run your command in my container, i got permission denied error. it seems, my docker container doesnt have access to this phantomjs binary file under /usr/bin/phantomjs.

This docker image is my personal project's image, and i am not sure should I use phantomjs as a docker container or it can be regular phantomjs on ubuntu ?

Comment: So obviously something is wrong. You will nee to provide an [mcve] if you want us to help you.

Comment: ok now i am using phantomjs as a docker container and my java code connects to this docker container. Now everything is ok. Thanks for help.https://hub.docker.com/r/wernight/phantomjs/   This repo can help if someone has same problem. Dont forget set docker machine ip as a phantomjs machine ip.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked in my application is

***dockerfile***

```
FROM openjdk:11
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY build/libs/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080 9090 8000

ENV PHANTOMJS_VERSION 2.1.1
RUN wget -q -O phantomjs.tar.bz2 https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-$PHANTOMJS_VERSION-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 \
    && tar -f phantomjs.tar.bz2 -xj phantomjs-$PHANTOMJS_VERSION-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs \
    && mv phantomjs-$PHANTOMJS_VERSION-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/ \
    && rm -rf phantomjs-$PHANTOMJS_VERSION-linux-x86_64 phantomjs.tar.bz2


ENTRYPOINT ["java","-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8000","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

and then I can use `phantomjs` in java `spring-boot` directly

***My java code***

```
List<String> cmdArgs = new ArrayList<String>(5);
cmdArgs.add("phantomjs");

// Other code and other phantomjs args 

ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command(cmdArgs.toArray(new String[] {}));
Process process = proc.start();

if (process.waitFor() == 0 || process.exitValue() == 0) // Wait for PhantomJS to complete 
{
    ok = true;
}
else
{
    errorMsg = String.valueOf(process.exitValue());
}
```